# Issue with TypeScript definition files when generating proto definitions with protoc-gen-grpc-web

Tags: protoc, grpc-web

I'm having an issue with my generated proto definitions.

I'm using the most up to date version of the `protoc-gen-grpc-web` which I got from [here (version 1.0.7)](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases).

Note: I've had the same problem on both MacOS and Windows as well as on version 1.0.5.

The problem I have is my generated definitions are missing the `.` separating the `Class` from its namespace.

Eg. my output would be something as follows:

```
import * as jspb from "google-protobuf"

import * as google_protobuf_timestamp_pb from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb';
import * as google_protobuf_empty_pb from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/empty_pb';
import * as common_basic_pb from './common/basic_pb';
import * as contact_mechanism_pb from './contact_mechanism_pb';
import * as banking_detail_pb from './banking_detail_pb';
...

export namespace IncomeTax {
  export type AsObject = {
    id: string,
    personId: string,
    dateCreated?: google_protobuf_timestamp_pb.Timestamp.AsObject,
    lastUpdated?: google_protobuf_timestamp_pb.Timestamp.AsObject,
    fromDate?: google_protobuf_timestamp_pb.Timestamp.AsObject,
    thruDate?: google_protobuf_timestamp_pb.Timestamp.AsObject,
    taxNumber: string,
    country?: contact_mechanism_pbCountry.AsObject,
  }
}
```

See the line `country?: contact_mechanism_pbCountry.AsObject,`.

`contact_mechanism_pbCountry` should be `contact_mechanism_pb.Country`.

This happens for every case of `common_basic_pb`, `contact_mechanism_pb` and `banking_details_pb`.

But not for the cases of `google_protobuf_timestamp_pb` and `google_protobuf_empty_pb`.

Here is what my `gen-protos` script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ./src/gen

protoc -I=../protos/                                   \
       ../protos/*.proto                               \
       ../protos/**/*.proto                            \
       ../protos/**/**/*.proto                         \
       ../protos/**/**/**/*.proto                      \
       --js_out=import_style=commonjs:./src/gen \
       --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:./src/gen
```

I've tried so many different things but I just can't get the expected output with this tool.

Comment: Any git repo with reproducible example?

Comment: Seems like a similar issue as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/693 but not quite the same? Can you log an issue to the repo please?

Comment: I already did that 6 days ago over here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by a fix which was merged into the project 29 days ago. The project owners have announced that they will make a new release soon.

More details around that can be found [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/805).

The new release of the tool will be `version 1.0.8`